# How to describe how a cat looks when groomed?

Tags: single-word-requests, animals

What is a word to describe how a cat looks when it's groomed?

My husband described it as *nappy*, which I don't think would be the correct word. To give an image of what I am trying to describe, think of a medium-haired cat that licked its fur and looks messy, with wet fur sticking up a bit.

It's a weird request and may be too specific, but I hope there's some kind of answer to what I am asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345649/is-there-a-word-to-describe-the-appearance-of-wet-hair.  "Bedraggled", from that answer, might work here.

Comment: Nappy is reasonable though maybe not the best choice; [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nappy) says "having a hairy, fuzzy, or downy surface", with examples referring to old sweaters as well as to fabrics with a nap (velvet etc). Sadly Googling *nappy cat* just gets cat diapers, so maybe more research is needed.

Comment: Do you have a picture of a cat in such a state? That might help.

Comment: In Cartoonland, we can easily see if Marge Simpson or Lois Griffin have just had sex - they have ***bedraggled hair**!*

Comment: "Groomed" usually means "made to look pretty", so if the cat is making itself messy it isn't really "grooming" itself.

Comment: I was going to say 'sleek' until I realised you don't mean 'groomed'. Perhaps 'spiky'.

Comment: I suggest **preened** which word originates in regard to birds and feathers but has a wider application also [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/preened_adj?tab=meaning_and_use#9928868867).

Comment: @DJClayworth I guess that's the difference between what a pet groomer does and animals grooming themselves or others. In the latter case they don't care what humans think of their appearance (not that cats generally care what we think in the first place).

Comment: Yes, a pet groomer grooms pets. And animals sometimes groom themselves, meaning cleaning themselves or making themselves neat. But what you are describing is an animal doing something else to itself, making itself messy. That's not grooming, as WeatherVane says.

Answer (score 1):

The places where the fur sticks up would be *cowlicks*. The adjective **cowlicked** sees [occasional usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cowlicked%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2016,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en), and would appropriately describe the state of the cat's fur.

Comment: Hah ha, so the cat knows it sticks out and tries to wet it back?

Comment: Surely *catlicked* would be more sensible.